# How to exit an air application from an actionscript library?

Tags: apache-flex, air, flexcover

I am trying the following but every once in awhile the nativeApp is not defined.

```
var nativeApp:Object =  getDefinitionByName("flash.desktop.NativeApplication");
nativeApp.nativeApplication.exit();
```

I am confused why sometimes getDefinitionByName("flash.desktop.NativeApplication") resolves and other times it does not.

I am trying to resolve this problem to address the following issue in flexcover - code.google.com/p/flexcover/issues/detail?id=33

Update - here is the class I am attempting to fix: http://code.google.com/p/flexcover/source/browse/trunk/CoverageAgent/src/com/allurent/coverage/runtime/AbstractCoverageAgent.as  CoverageAgent.swc is an actionscript library called by the unit tests to exit the flexcover air application used to determine the code coverage of the unit tests.  The flexcover air application only exits about the half the time and it is causing problems for our maven builds to execute successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regards to FlexCover - the reason you are seeing it work sometimes and not others is the CoverageAgent is designed to exit the Unit Tests it does not communicate back to the CoverageViewer. I have created my own FlexCoverListener that sends an exit message over local connection to the CoverageViewer. Below is the code.

```
package org.flexunit.listeners
{
import flash.events.EventDispatcher;

import org.flexunit.listeners.closer.FlexCoverCloser;
import org.flexunit.runner.IDescription;
import org.flexunit.runner.Result;
import org.flexunit.runner.notification.Failure;
import org.flexunit.runner.notification.IAsyncStartupRunListener;
import org.flexunit.runner.notification.ITemporalRunListener;

public class FlexCoverListener extends EventDispatcher implements IAsyncStartupRunListener,    
ITemporalRunListener
{
  import com.allurent.coverage.runtime.CoverageManager;

  public function FlexCoverListener()
  {
  }

  public function get ready():Boolean 
  {
      return true;
  }

  public function testTimed( description:IDescription, runTime:Number ):void
  {

  }


  public function testRunFinished( result:Result ):void 
  {
      CoverageManager.agent.recordCoverage("SR_TESTS_COMPLETE");
  }

  public function testFinished( description:IDescription ):void {}

  public function testRunStarted( description:IDescription ):void {}


  public function testStarted( description:IDescription ):void{}


  public  function testFailure( failure:Failure ):void{}


  public function testAssumptionFailure( failure:Failure ):void{}


  public function testIgnored( description:IDescription ):void{}
  }
  }
```

You can add the above listener to your tests by doing the following in your TestRunner:

```
core.addListener(new FlexCoverListener());
var core : FlexUnitCore = new FlexUnitCore();
```

Last but most importantly I changed the `recordCoverage` method in the `AbstractCoverageAgent` to look like the following:

```
/**
     * Record the execution of a single coverage key; called by
     * the global coverage() function.
     */
    public function recordCoverage(key:String):void
    {
        if(key == "SR_TESTS_COMPLETE")
        {
            exit();    
        }
        else if (isNaN(coverageMap[key]++))
        {
            // The map must not have contained this key yet, so enter an
            // execution count of 1.  Subsequent calls will autoincrement without
            // returning NaN.
            //
            coverageMap[key] = 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hurrah! This works!  If you want you should work with blegros (https://github.com/blegros/flexunit) to get this into flexunit.

Also make sure to include the core.addListener(new CIListener()) for Maven/Hudson.

Answer (score 2):

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
```

Comment: +1 `nativeApplication` is a static field, so it should be accessed like a static field.

Comment: What import should I use?  When I try import flash.desktop.NativeApplication in the actionscript library then it could not be found.

Comment: I don't know.  Aren't you using Flash Builder?  After NativeApplication hit Control-Space.  Who remembers imports anymore? :-)

Comment: Do you have the AIR libraries in the build path?

Comment: ok, I have included the airglobal.swc in the build path.  Thanks!  But now I am back in the same boat where "Variable flash.desktop::NativeApplication is not defined."  This problem seems to be somehow related to executing the testrunner swf from an ANT script.  Could that be causing this problem of the variable not resolving?

Comment: I posted a specific resolution below. While all the answers are correct about how to exit an air application this would not have solved the issue. This is specific to how FlexCover communicates with its CoverageViewer and it does not have built in support (at least one that works) to exit when the tests are completed. See answer below for more details.

Answer (score 0):

`nativeAppilcation` is a static field. It does not need to be called on an object. So you do not have to call `getDefinitionByName("flash.desktop.NativeApplication")`.

Just invoke exit as follows:

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
```

Flash Builder or Flash Pro will include the library for you.
If you are not using the IDE, import the library:

```
import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;
```