# Action Script 3 - Make a quit app/progam button on MouseEvent.CLICK

Tags: windows, actionscript-3, flash, mouseevent

toddling through AS3. I was wandering if someone could give me any pointers on how to make it so when a button is clicked, it prompts a balloon to appear so you can 'quit out' of flash. This is from fullscreen mode - post development.

I'm new to AS3 so any tips would be appreciated.

```
quitout_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, quitout);

function quitout(event:MouseEvent):void
{
 something happens here.....
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also be looking for fscommand("quit")

```
import flash.system.fscommand;
```

Then run

```
function quitout(event:MouseEvent):void
{
     fscommand("quit")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.NORMAL;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558443/full-screen-interactive-mode-the-allow-button-click-is-passed-to-the-applicat) to trigger fullscreen to windowed mode via code.

[NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768594/close-air-app-where-is-it) for exiting the application (if you're in an desktop AIR application)